# Jekyll - Create Multiple Landing Pages from One Markdown File

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am trying to create two web pages from the same markdown file, is this possible? I have two layouts `test1.html` and `test2.html`. I want to generate two pages from the layouts above based on one markdown file `data.md` in order for ab testing... is this doable in jekyll?

Comment: You can use a [generator plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/), but the easiest way is to use a service like [netlify split testing](https://www.netlify.com/docs/split-testing/).

Comment: To generate the files, you could create two markdown files, `test1.md` and `test2.md`, and include the content of `data.md` by using `{% include_relative data.md %}` in them. That would generate the two files without duplicating the content in `data.md`. (You would still need a split-testing service like Netlify's, as @DavidJacquel suggests, to divide the traffic to the two options.)